# Google Sheets conditional formatting a row based on finding either of two words in a string

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Users are able to enter a string into a cell. If the string contains either the word "Letter" and/or the word "Note", the entire row needs to turn red. These words are not case sensitive. I can create two conditional formats for the same row but would prefer one that looks for either word. One person had me try =OR(SEARCH(“LETTER”,$M6),SEARCH(“NOTE”,$M6)) in the "Conditional Formula_  Custom Formula is", it did not work. This works for the word "letter" in a string:  =SEARCH("LETTER",$M6). This works for the word "note" in a string:  =SEARCH("note",$M6). I would like to put them into one statement.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXMATCH($M6, "(?i)LETTER|NOTE")
```

[image]